# What part of a non-restrictive relative clause corefers?

Tags: syntax, pronouns, relative-clauses, binding-theory

I am trying to figure out what components of a non-restrictive relative clause (if any) corefer with a previously mentioned antecedent. Here is the example I am working with:

“Mandy Monroe, one of the newest members, asked me….”

With this example, does the entire clause [one of the newest members] corefer with [Mandy Monroe]? (Or does it not corefer at all)? Any help on this is welcome!

PS: Please let me know if this isn't actually a non-restrictive relative clause.

Comment: I'd call it an appositive, not a relative clause.

Comment: It can't be a relative clause since there is no relativized element that is linked to an antecedent. It's actually an appositive noun phrase, more specifically a supplementary appositive NP. You can tell it's an appositive NP by the fact that it can be substituted for the whole NP yielding an entailment of the original. Your example entails _one of the newest members asked me…._

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for letting me know! So, regarding my original question, is any part of this appositive NP corefering with [Mandy Monroe]?

Comment: No, appositives do not co-refer as such, but have an 'anchor'. In this case, the appositive is adjacent to the anchor.

Comment: Many linguists who are not as firmly committed to monostratal explanations consider appositives to be merely the remains of deceased non-restrictive relative clauses. The "anchor" that @BillJ refers to could be considered an avatar of the missing relative pronoun, which would co-refer if it were not deleted by _Whiz_-Deletion.

Comment: The absolutely essential property of a relative clause is the presence (overt or covert) of a relativized element that is anaphoric to some expression in the matrix clause. If such an element is not present, it cannot in any way at all be a relative clause, whatever one may wish to call it. The noun phrase "one of the newest members" is simply a non-restrictive supplement, a loosely attached interpolation, set off with commas and by a pause in speech.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that your example is a reduced non-restrictive relative clause.  For evidence that appositives of this sort are reduced clauses, see [McCawley's discussion of appositives](https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&pg=PA469&lpg=PA469&dq=mccawley%20phenomena%20appositive&source=bl&ots=uOlA8M7xVc&sig=_T79D8HlAAHJaw3rl2goAtL9u8c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnqoP31IjUAhXIslQKHekzB8cQ6AEINjAD#v=onepage&q=mccawley%20phenomena%20appositive&f=false).  However, in the clause "(who is) one of the newest members", the expression "one of the newest members" is not in a coreferential position.  It predicates something of "who".  The term "coreference" is ordinarily reserved for presupposed coreference, not asserted reference, as we have here.  There is discussion of the difference between asserted and presupposed reference in Postal's book *Crossover phenomena* (1971).

Comment: Thanks for the suggested readings, I'll have to take a look at them. So would you say that this is the case for all non-restrictive relative clauses (reduced or not)? Because I have another one that goes like this:

"Mandy's husband, the president of the club, has been...."

Here, I assumed that [the president of the club] was coreferential with [Mandy's husband]. What do you think?

Comment: Please review the last part of my answer.  "the president of the club" is an **asserted** reference.  To speak of it being coreferential with "Mandy's husband" is confusing at best.

Comment: @BillJ, please read over the reference I gave to the evidence given in McCawley's discussion.  In modern linguistics, we deal with evidence, not just terminology.

Comment: Oh please! I follow H&P who give evidence for all their claims. As it happens, on looking at the OP's example again,  I think the NP "one of the newest members" is ascriptive (not specifying) and hence not an appositive. It is still a supplement, of course, with "Mandy Monroe" as anchor, but it's a modifier, not an appositive. It's not some 'reduced relative' clause (a ridiculous misnomer if ever there was one) as you call it.